# How to REALLY create a foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

This sounds like a stupid question, because there's literally hundreds of tutorials out there.

But no matter which tutorial I follow to create a `foreign key` or, in my case, a `composite foreign key`, even though the table creation is always successful, MySQL Workbench does not show any `foreign key` information.

If I create these 2 example tables

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
id INT NOT NULL,
category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id, category)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
info TEXT,
CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (id, category) REFERENCES parent(id, category)
);
```

The table creation is successful but the foreign key is not listed.
[image]

What am I missing? This is really weird behavior that their is neither an error nor a warning shown by MySQL Workbench.

Comment: What is the default storage engine (`SELECT @@default_storage_engine`)? If it is not "InnoDB" then you will have to specify `ENGINE=InnoDB` as a table option when you create both `parent` and `child`. Foreign keys are not supported on other storage engines.

Comment: what does `show create table child;` output?

Comment: @BillKarwin SELECT @@default_storage_engine says "InnoDB"

Comment: @ysth show create table child does show CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY, but why is it not listed in the table info?

Comment: no clue; I've never used workbench, but from the questions people ask here, it seems in general like a great way to not see what's really happening :)

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101484 ?

Comment: I have MySQL Workbench installed, but I hardly ever use it. I have always found it harder to use than the command-line client.

Comment: @ysth Looks like this is simply a bug in the GUI and not a problem with my approach. I guess I can just go on with my project without having to worry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested your example tables in MySQL Workbench 8.0.28. It  successfully created the `child` table with its foreign key. I ran `SHOW CREATE TABLE child` and the output shows the foreign key.

But MySQL Workbench apparently has a bug showing the foreign key in the visual table information. I viewed the foreign keys tab as you did. I pressed the "refresh" button and got this message:

> **Error**
>
> Unhandled exception: invalid column constraint_name for resultset
>
> Check the log for more details.

I checked the log (Help->Show Log File) and saw this:

```
10:15:53 [ERR][sqlide_tableman_ext.py:show_table:1186]: Error initializing tab constraints: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/sqlide_tableman_ext.py", line 1183, in show_table
    tab.show_table(schema, table)
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/sqlide_tableman_ext.py", line 854, in show_table
    self.refresh()
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/sqlide_catalogman_ext.py", line 373, in refresh
    self.preload_data(self.get_query())
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/sqlide_catalogman_ext.py", line 367, in preload_data
    node.set_string(i, rset.stringFieldValueByName(field) or "" if format_func is None else format_func(rset.stringFieldValueByName(field)))
SystemError: invalid column constraint_name for resultset
```

This bug was reported in February 2021: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102496 (and also the duplicate bug ysth links to in the comments above). The bug is "Verified" which means the MySQL team acknowledges it as a bug, but there is no fix and no estimate for when there will be a fix.