# Is MYSQL not adding foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following simple table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE country (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  country_code varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE state (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  state_code varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  country_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),  
  KEY ky_state_country (country_id),  
  CONSTRAINT fk_state_country FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I open MySql workbench and looked at the foreign key tab, nothing is there and there is no errors.
I tried to remove the key definition ky_state_country and what I found that MySql workbench
show the fk_state_country in the index tab instead of the foreign key tab.

```
CREATE TABLE state (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  state_code varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  country_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),    
  CONSTRAINT fk_state_country FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

mysql  **Ver 8.0.25** for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

I'm expecting the have both index and foreign key. Am I missing something here?
I found I bug report, have a look in the link below.
[MYSQL Bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101484)
I'll probably update to version 8.029 and above and will update here.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I just tested it on my local instance, using your table definitions. I do see both the index and the FK constraint in Workbench.

Comment: I run the script in workbench, can you confirm that you did the same?

Comment: Yes, I tried both running the script in the command-line mysql client, then I dropped the tables and run the sql script in Workbench. Same result. I'm using MySQL 8.0.29 and Workbench 8.0.29 on MacOS.

Comment: so you see the ky_ in index and the fk_ in foreign key ?

Comment: Yes I do see both. Can you try to "refresh all"? Right-click on the table in the schema inspector on the left.

Comment: Oh, wait a second - I was looking in the table inspector on the left. I don't see the foreign key in the visual table info. This sounds like a familiar problem.  See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71561116/how-to-really-create-a-foreign-key-in-mysql/71561722#71561722

Comment: Ok, so I don't need to do anything I guess, can you just show me the command I need to run, maybe in command line to prove that the foreign key is created? Thanks @BillKarwin

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>`

Comment: For what it's worth, I hardly ever use MySQL Workbench. It has always been full of these sorts of frustrating bugs. I don't find it helps my productivity at all, quite the contrary.

Comment: I have long script to run and workbench has editor, I like to use tool rather than command line, you're welcome to sugest alternative free tool that supprt mysql :-)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html has an editor, can run SQL scripts, is free. In fact, it is bundled with the MySQL distribution.

Comment: I'm talking about desktop applciation, I looked at toad just now I think it's free for mysql

Comment: Yes, Toad is probably the best GUI client for MySQL. I forget what their current license is, you can check it out.

Comment: Not sure if it free yet